# TypeORM migrations: How to stop generating unnecessary queries

Tags: express, mariadb, typeorm, ts-node

I am facing an issue where I am seeing unwanted SQL queries being generated every time I run a TypeORM migration. These queries include updates to columns in my database tables, even though I have not made any changes to the corresponding entities in my codebase.

I am unsure why these queries are being generated and I would like to understand how to prevent them from being generated in the future. I have checked my version control system for any recent commits or changes to the migration files and double-checked my entities to make sure that the columns haven't been changed but the problem persist.

I am looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.
typeOrm version used 0.2.45
ts-node version I used 10.9.1
db type mariadb

I double-checking my entities to make sure that the columns haven't been changed. I was expecting the migration to only include the necessary changes to reflect any changes made to the entities, I also I deleted all the migration file and I generate them again and with same problem.